# Is Stanford encyclopedia of philosophy a good place for beginners?

Tags: reference-request, learning-methods, introduction-to-philosophy

I have always been told that SEP is good place to start for any unfamiliar philosophical topic. However, I feel that many of its articles are too academic and unfriendly. One entry always leads to infinitely many other entries, and reading an SEP entry pops up more questions rather than satisfies my initial need for familiarity with a new topic. Is it my problem or SEP’s problem? If it is mine, what is the right way of using SEP?

Comment: On my impression, [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/) is somewhat more accessible, typically. For quick orientation even some Wikipedia articles may do, but everything there should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: I generally do not recommend SEP to beginners.in philosophy  I have been doing reading in philosophy for decades now, and my experience is similar to yours.    As Conifold noted, IEP is usually more accessible.  Even better for a beginner is Britannica.  Wikipedia is erratic, about half of their articles are the best intro I have found, the other half are either useless, or even worse, misleading.  Sometimes a search for the question, and the word "introduction" or "summary" finds a different useful source, and sometimes points to good Quora answers.

Comment: SEP is something to come back to, AFTER you get an introduction to a topic elsewhere, and then explore it a bit by reading a paper or two, or having a discussion or two.

Answer (score 3):

**Well, it depends on what you mean by 'beginner'.**

On the one hand, a beginner in philosophy might be a PhD in mathematics who is interested in questions of foundations. They might have a yearning to understand the history and logic of the development of set theory or category theory and understand how it relates to the philosophy of mathematics or science, and so on.

On the other hand, a beginner may be a curious high school student who has started to understand that "facts" aren't often as reliable as one is led to believe by their parents, church, or government. Such a person might be a half-way decent user of English but not even a native speaker.

The SEP is an *advanced* "introductory" resource for someone with a solid command of college-level English and a general familiarity with philosophy terminology, and it hosts a plethora of articles from the relatively introductory to the relatively technical. Most entries presume a fair amount of philosophical terminology like modality, epistemological, metaphysics, ontological, or have references to important contributors to philosophy in the Western tradition like (in no particular order) Russell, Aristotle, Grice, Husserl, and Kant. It certainly helps if you have a general, undergraduate-level familiarity with Western philosophy, both history and vocabulary.

At a bare minimum, before you start reading the SEP, I'd start with WP's ["philosophy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy#Historical_overview). They also have a [philosophy portal here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Philosophy). If you can, it also helps to know there's are other tertiary resources out there, like the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/) and the [Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Philosophy). Routledge and Blackwell have resources too, which if you can afford or check out will help build a pool of general references. If I pick a question that interests me, and I attempt to answer, I will usually poke around all of these references if I'm not very familiar.

Before the SEP, you might want to consider getting some ["101" books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_101/fHwXygEACAAJ?hl=en) and then direct your studies towards an introductory series. I have a few of the Very Short Introduction books by Oxford, like [Critchley's *Continental philosophy: a very short introduction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Continental_Philosophy_A_Very_Short_Intr/YeoRDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), and they're excellent. Once you have a general feel for what an undergraduate would have a familiarity with, in terms of history and terminology, you'll find that the SEP will be a good resource if you find a paper or an advanced book on the topic. For instance, from my own interests, the article [Computation in Physical Systems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/) led to me purchasing some expensive and technical works, starting with a [work by author of the article](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physical_Computation/rtAkCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). It also helps to have a familiarity with terms, like here at WP's [glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_philosophy). [Oxford has a dictionary](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199541430.001.0001/acref-9780199541430), part of which is online.

That being said, the historical articles are generally the best for a complete novice, because they are half-historical, half-terminological. There are also some topics that are easier to decode than others.

Examples of simpler articles:

- [Ordinary Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ordinary-objects/) - Talking about the existence of everyday things.
- [Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle/) - One of the biggies!
- [Presocratic Philosophers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presocratics/) - There's more to Ancient Greece than Socrates, Plato, and Aristotle!
- [Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presocratics/) - Like ontology, ethics, and epistemology, an important, frequently-used (though not universally agreed upon) term

But, if you find yourself getting frustrated with SEP entries, a perfectly legitimate way to gain knowledge is through introductory videos on YT. One very popular resource is [Academy of Ideas](https://www.youtube.com/c/academyofideas) which has almost one and a half million subscribers with videos that have been viewed by millions of people. If you put yourself on a steady diet of these, in no time, you'll be picking up who and what are the important ideas in philosophy.

And if you get stuck, or have questions, then you're already at the right place. See if you can't find some assistance by searching for the question or term here, and if not, do a little reading, and post your question. There's more philosophical expertise hanging around at this site than at any institution in the world, but you'll have to learn to sift the chaff from the wheat which can be a bit challenging.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive and helpful answer! Indeed different SEP entries have different levels of difficulty. I find Prof. Inwagen’s entry on metaphysics friendly and interesting, but some other entries highly esoteric, even for those who have already gained some undergraduate-level philosophy experience

Comment: @Papuseme The construction of knowledge is approximative. One starts with a rough model then revises. WP is a better first iteration than nothing.  Certainly the articles are more lucid than primary references. Besides, this is a Q&A site, not Nous. Besides, WP has a fantastic price.

Comment: Unless youre on John Searle's level, you might want to reconsider haughty. Humility is a virtue.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is -- sort of, its you, and sort of, its SEP.

The SEP reflects the state of academic philosophy.  It uses a lot of technical jargon, focusses a microscope on what seem to outsiders to be subtle and unimportant issues, and overall is very inaccessible to people interested in philosophical questions who are not immersed in the Analytic approach to philosophy.  BUT -- for those with an analytic mindset, it provides a high quality summary of the thinking in that community on multiple philosophic questions.  If you are a beginner academic philosopher, say a grad student who wants to get better grounded in one of the subjects you are not yet well versed in, the SEP article will be a great place to start.

If you have perhaps 1-2 introductory undergraduate classes in philosophy, or none, then the SEP is a very poor starting point.

The Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy can be similarly technical, but with shorter articles, and the IEP generally has a much better introduction.  The IEP is usually a better starting point.

When I am looking for a summary to recommend to people outside the academic philosophy community, I rarely recommend either. Surprisingly, Wikipedia is often the best summary I have found for many philosophical topics.  As always with Wikipedia though, quality control is -- irregular.  I also often find widely held but false beliefs embedded in Wiki articles.  I give Wikipedia an about 50% score on usefulness.  BUT -- one needs to actually know something about the subject to distinguish poor from good Wiki articles, so for self-education, Wiki is not   trustworthy.  One needs a Wiki article endorsed by an expert before one can trust it.

For self education for non-academic philosophy, the most consistent source I have found is Britannica.

I also do google searches, with the topic and "summary".  Blogs and Quora answers are often good starting points.

If you are serious about philosophy, even if you do not lean toward either academic philosophy or the Analytic school, as I do not, then you will still find SEP to be very useful.  Not as the first place to go, but as maybe the 4th.  Get the intro elsewhere, look up a few papers on the subject, then dig into SEP to figure out some of the context and background for the WHY of what others are doing.

Comment: +1 Sounds about right!

Answer (score 1):

This is one explanation of why you may find SEP "unfriendly". Another is that it is so much fun that you it takes up too much of your time. So:

Despite being an "encyclopaedia" it is not a good resource for rote learning. I find you need to **follow** the article, not just parse sentences, if you are to find it "friendly" despite knowing nothing about the topic. This is in contrast with wikipedia, but wikipedia is often misleading in a number of ways. But the SEP is nevertheless readable on its own.

### An example chosen without thought

> “Autonomy” literally means giving the law to oneself, and on Kant’s
> view our understanding provides laws that constitute the a priori
> framework of our experience. Our understanding does not provide the matter or content of our experience, but it does provide the basic formal structure within which we experience any matter received through our senses.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant/#MorFre

If you are just looking for **factoids**, this might come off as **too long winded** to learn from. What relevance is anything that is being said, to anything else?

It's not until I link 'a priori framework of our experience' to 'structure within which we experience', that I see the *difference* between "a priori" and "matter received through the senses". I notice then that the latter, unlike at least some a priori "structures", is not provided by "understanding".

That's because "laws that constitute the a priori framework of our experience" could mean anything to me. What is meant by 'laws'? Not, it turns out, behavioural norms, which then excludes most conventional senses of 'law'.

The article goes on to say that (what Kant means by) "understanding" tells us about *laws of experience, not morality*, and explains how these are the same (both are the subject of philosophy) and different (different cognitive faculties). I can then work out in **what way**

> To summarise:
>
> Theoretical philosophy is about how the world is (A633/B661)... Practical
> philosophy is about how the world ought to be (ibid.,
> A800–801/B828–829)

Which may be the sort of happy fact you wanted to know when looking at an encyclopaedia: the background explanation of 'understanding' **support this summary**.

So try to **paraphrase** (philosophy is amenable to paraphrase) what is being said, at the level of, say, each paragraph, ideally without ignoring anything. Then you may be able to **digest** what is being said.

---

The IEP is easier to read, but I don't think it will be helpful to explain why.

Personally, I find it frustrating that it often uses logical notation. It's always, so far, been fear of mathematics rather than inability to work out what is being said.

Comment: Kinda a weird answer maybe

Comment: Just spent over an hour explaining, with examples, why something might be difficult to read and how to get around that LOL

Comment: +1 I agree the IEP is easier, and certainly the formal logic makes some articles tough to get through!

Comment: it's just really off putting @JD

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The two main scholarly online references are the IEP (the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy) and the SEP. Both of them are of very high quality and unlike much of Wikipedia, it tends to be internally consistent. The SEP, as you have already noted, is much more academic than the IEP. The IEP takes a much friendlier approach.

Try it, see how you find it.

Answer (score 1):

I never find the SEP easy to learn from either, the articles are so complicated when you're just getting started. The IEP is a lot better for beginning with but I found it missed a couple of topics and did have some complicated articles too. I found great success learning from introductory books on philosophy like Prof Michael Jubien's Contempory Metaphysics.

Comment: +1 Glad to see you branch out into responses!